# Vuetify Dialog closes on Vuex mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

I am using Vue 2, Vuetify and Vuex. I have encountered an issue where the Vuetify Dialog closes on Vuex Store mutation.

Basically, I make an API call which gets the search results of a particular query. I store it in a variable called searchresults. This is an object that has attributes like status, where one has to confirm or deny the assignment. For every entry in the object you can click on it to open a dialog box. The dialog box displays information from searchresults and allows you to confirm or deny the assignment. It makes another API call to update the status for that entry. Note, here searchresults will not reflect this change. You can check if its updated on page refresh.

After making the second API call, I update the status for that particular Object entry in searchresults to reflect the change. The vuetify dialog box is closing automatically after this update. I don’t want the dialog to close. I have used ‘persistent’ prop for v-dialog as well.

Thank you for your help. I apologize I could not replicate the problem in codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: The issue for this is hard to find without looking at your code. There are many possible causes. Can you edit the post to include a minimal example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.